# Call the function in if only one

Tags: angular

I implemented **(window:resize)** on **Angular 5**.

Is it possible to call the function in **if** only once?

When my window screen is **>= 551px** (for example: **600px**):

- Value is **600px**

When I resize my window screen to example **700px**:

- Value is **700px**

So my question is:

It is possible to check my window screen **ONLY ONCE?**
At the moment value is like this one:

> = 551px,
>   552px,
>   553px,
>   554px,
>   555px,
>   etc.

I would like to this one:

When my window screen is **>= 551px** (for example: **600px**):

- Value is **551px**

When I resize my window screen to example **300px** (**<= 551px**):

- Value is **500px**

Check if only once, only if value higher than **551px** or **550px** - not every time when I resize window.

**StackBlitz:**
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5-example-v8a3xw?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: I guess you call a function which is defined in a component. Why not just store the state in the component, e.g. as a boolean, and then check at the start of the function if the condition is met or not.

Comment: As @Akkusativobjekt just said, store the state of the current size. The (window:resize) will run on every resize but you can do a conditional change of the state whenever you deem necessary.